# Construct object name, then pass object to function?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on existing Javascript code, which uses datasets stored in objects which are named data1, data2, etc. The numbers are IDs taken from a database.

Now, I need to write a little additional function which takes the IDs as input, then constructs the appropriate object name using that Id, and then passes that object to a function as a parameter.

So, something like:

```
function doStuff(id){
    var objname="data"+id;
    //now, I need to pass the object (not just the name) to a function
    someFunction(objname);    //this obviously doesn't work, because it just passes the object name as a string
}
```

So, how do I pass the actual object to the function, given that I have the object name?

The question sounds elementary, and I assume there's a method which does just this, but google doesn't seem to help.

Comment: This implied the object exists, right? You should construct a key-value array them to establish the relationship.

Comment: So, in other words, to test this example code, you'd need two lines like `data1 = 'one';` and `data2 = 'two';`, right?

Comment: Yes, the object exists already. So creating an array with IDs as keys and objects as values, and then getting an array member by ID should work?

Comment: @phihag Not sure what you're trying to say - the test code obviously doesn't work, it's just an illustration of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes that should work - try it!

Comment: Thanks Floris, that works. If you want to post your suggestion as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: OK robert - it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the objects exist, you need a way to "find" them. I suggest you create a relationship between the string and the object using a key-value array - the key is the string, and the value is the object. You can then index the array with the string, and it will return the object.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object and store in it keys like so:

```
var obj = {
    data0 : "example 1",
    data1 : "example 2"
}
```

Then you can access the properties like so:

```
function doStuff(id) {
    var key = "data" + id;
    someFunction(key);
}

someFunction(key) {
    return obj[key];
}
```